# grok favorite colour

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
phonebook = {}

line = input('Name and colour: ')
while line:
  name, number = line.split()
  phonebook[name] = number
  line = input('Name and number: ')

for i in phonebook:
  print(i, phonebook[i])
```

The code is meant to turn out like this:

```
Name and colour: Nicky Blue

Name and colour: James Yellow

Name and colour: Sam Red

Name and colour: 

Sam Red

Nicky Blue

James Yellow
```

I get:

```
Name and colour: Nicky Blue

Name and number: James Yellow

Name and number: Sam Red

Name and number:

Nicky Blue

James Yellow

Sam Red
```

Does any one know a fix to this?

Comment: Why should the code output such stuff? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its correct, its just on the other 3 lines it says ***number*** instead of ***colour***
Just a spelling mistake, not wrong code.

Script start with:
`line = input('Name and colour: ')`

and in the `while line` loop it states:

`line = input('Name and number: ')`

replace it with:

> `line = input('Name and colour: ')`

or viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the order that elements were inserted, you will need to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) instead of a dictionary object:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

phonebook = OrderedDict()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = {}
line = input('Name and colour: ')
while line:
  name, colour = line.split()
  user[name] = colour
  line = input('Name and colour: ')
for i in user:
  print(i, user[i])
```

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly this code answers the question?